# 2D movement issues

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a isometric game in javascript, so far it goes well. But I have some problems when a object it suppose to walk from point A to B.

```
Item.prototype.update = function(delta){
    var speed = 1; //<-- hard coded for now
    var deltaX = this.toX - this.x;
    var deltaY = this.toY - this.y;

    var radians = Math.atan2(deltaX, -deltaY) * (180 / Math.PI);
    var distance = Math.sqrt((deltaX*deltaX)+(deltaY*deltaY));

    this.x += Math.cos(radians) * Math.min(speed, distance) * delta;
    this.y += Math.sin(radians) * Math.min(speed, distance) * delta;
};
```

The problems I'm having is that the object that is moving does a strange 180 or 90 turn before it start to head in the right direction, and then slows down when it's near it's destination. I have no idea what causes the problems.

Comment: since javascript Math.cos and Math.sin works in radians , why you convert into  degrees :   var radians = Math.atan2(deltaX, -deltaY) * (180 / Math.PI); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slow down is probably caused because you take the Math.min(speed, distance) when distance is lower than your speed (implying that you can't move by your speed each frame (since it's dependant on the delta)).

Your code does not allow me to see what causes the issue with the turn you are describing.

To find out where exactly is your issue, I would suggest you trace your variables by writing their content to the console to see there the bad behaviour comes from.

Edit:

Here is a fix for your situation (I haven't tested in JS, but it works in python)

```
Item.prototype.update = function(delta){
    var speed = 1; //<-- hard coded for now
    var deltaX = this.toX - this.x;
    var deltaY = this.toY - this.y;

    //var radians = Math.atan2(deltaX, -deltaY) * (180 / Math.PI);
    var radians = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
    var distance = Math.sqrt((deltaX*deltaX)+(deltaY*deltaY));
    var max_distance = delta * speed;
    var distance_this_frame = Math.min(distance, max_distance);

    this.x += Math.cos(radians) * distance_this_frame;
    this.y += Math.sin(radians) * distance_this_frame;
};
```

You had two issues with your use of atan2: first, as pointed in the question's comment, why did you multiply your calculation by `(180 / Math.PI)`, and second, the parameters for atan2 are `y, x`, not `x, y`.

And as I pointed early, your use of `min` was not appropriate. Spamming stuff to the console helps see what values that should be constant vary and helps track where the problem is coming from. When I say *variables* I suggest to also include in there *calculations results*.

Comment: But if I remove `Math.min(speed, distance)` then everything keeps vibrating. EDIT: From what I can see all variables looks okay in the console.

Comment: @Yemto I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it works now without any issues. But I think it's a bit strange that atan2 takes y and x, when every other function I know takes x and y. Why I used `* (180 / Math.PI)` I'll just say, bad tutorials.

Comment: @Yemto Atan2 parameters order is most of the time `y, x`, but it's worthwhile to double check with the language/library documentation you're using.